# How to abstract Multiple reducers with similar actions

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have multiple entities in my application. Each entity is independent of others. So I have create a separate reducer for each entity and combining all of them while creating store.

Every entry has some common actions like

1) set list of items
2) add single item
3) update single item
4) remove single item

So pretty much in each reducer I have same kind of code repeating

**setting list**

```js
return {
        ...state,
        list: {
            ...state.list,
            ...action.list
        }
 };
```

**Adding Single Item**

```js
return {
        ...state,
        list: {
            ...state.items,
            [action.item.id]: {
                ...state.list[action.item.id],
                ...action.item
            }
        }
 };
```

..similar code for Update action and remove action

**Is there a how I can abstract out this code and still keep a separate reducer for each entity?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create [Higher Order Reducer](http://1ven.me/higher-order-reducers.html), which will be responsible for creating reducers for you:

```js
const createEntityReducer = constants => (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.set:
      return {
        ...state,
        list: {
          ...state.list,
          ...action.list
        }
      };
    case constants.add:
      return {
        ...state,
        list: {
          ...state.items,
          [action.item.id]: {
            ...state.list[action.item.id],
            ...action.item
          }
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Basically, we are creating a function, which will accept `constants` object and return new reducer, which changes the state, when according actions will be dispatched.

Next, you can create as much similar reducers as you wish:

```js
const entityReducer = createEntityReducer({
  set: "SET_ACTION_TYPE",
  add: "ADD_ACTION_TYPE"
});

const entityReducer2 = createEntityReducer({
  set: "SET_ACTION_TYPE_2",
  add: "ADD_ACTION_TYPE_2"
});

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    entityReducer,
    entityReducer2
  })
);
```

If you want to handle custom actions in these reducers, you can create another Higher Order Reducer for that:

```js
const withCustomActions = (reducer) => (state, action) => {
  // that's the state, returned from initial reducer
  const nextState = reducer(state, action);

  switch (action.type) {
    case "CUSTOM_ACTION":
      return {
        ...nextState,
        key: action.value
      };
    default:
      return nextState;
  }
}

const entityReducer3 = withCustomActions(entityReducer);
```

Comment: Thanks 1ven, if we create reducers this fashion, how can I add additional actions which are specific to that entity reducer, Is there an easy way to extend this?

Comment: @hashbytes yeah, that's easy. I've updated the answer